# understanding variadic template function

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates

I'm new to variadic templates and recently came across it. I think I've not fully understood how it works in the background. I tried to write a variadic function **min** which returns the minimum of the arguments.

Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
T min(T v) {
    std::cout << "Base func:     " << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n";
    return v;
}

template<typename T, typename... Args>
T min(T first, Args... args) {
    std::cout << "Variadic func: " << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n";
    return first < min(args...) ? first : min(args...);
}

int main(){

    std::cout << min(3,2,1,0) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I used `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` to get more details of the instantiation of the functions and here's the output:

```
Variadic func: T min(T, Args ...) [with T = int; Args = {int, int, int}]
Variadic func: T min(T, Args ...) [with T = int; Args = {int, int}]
Variadic func: T min(T, Args ...) [with T = int; Args = {int}]
Base func:     T min(T) [with T = int]
Base func:     T min(T) [with T = int]
Variadic func: T min(T, Args ...) [with T = int; Args = {int}]
Base func:     T min(T) [with T = int]
Base func:     T min(T) [with T = int]
Variadic func: T min(T, Args ...) [with T = int; Args = {int, int}]
Variadic func: T min(T, Args ...) [with T = int; Args = {int}]
Base func:     T min(T) [with T = int]
Base func:     T min(T) [with T = int]
Variadic func: T min(T, Args ...) [with T = int; Args = {int}]
Base func:     T min(T) [with T = int]
Base func:     T min(T) [with T = int]
0
```

The code returns a correct output but I'm still fuzzy how functions are being called. Are all arguments are compared with each other? E.g. `3` will be compared with `2,1,0`, `2` will be compared with `1,0` and `1` will be compared with `0`? It'll be great if someone can give a solid reasoning to what exactly is happening?

Thanks

Comment: Keep in mind you're recursing twice in some cases.

Comment: The big problem is that the code you write recurses *twice* on one branch.  Cache the results of `min(args...)` instead of calling it twice and your trace printouts will make much more sense.

Comment: Why not print out the value of `first` (and `v` in the base function) so you can see how they're being called.

Comment: Yes, I think I'm recursing twice! didn't click that to me earlier. Then how it should be implemented to recurse only once? is that possible?

Comment: `auto r = min(args...);`  Then compare `first` and `r`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The call hierarchy is the following. The variadic function calls the "one less" function twice because `first < min(args...) ? first : min(args...);` calls it once to compare it to `first` (marked with `// compare`) and a second time if that comparison is `false` (marked with `// value`).

```
min(3,2,1,0) // compare
  -> min(2,1,0) // compare
    -> min(1,0) // compare
      ->min(0) // compare
      ->min(0) // value
    -> min(1,0) // value
      ->min(0) // compare
      ->min(0) // value
  -> min(2,1,0) // value
    -> min(1,0) // compare
      ->min(0) // compare
      ->min(0) // value
    -> min(1,0) // value
      ->min(0) // compare
      ->min(0) // value
```

I hope this makes it more readable for you.

Comment: Thank you @WorldSEnder, this clarified my doubts with the function callings...Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you unroll the template calls and fix tbe double recursion by caching the result of the recurse value, it should look like this

And this is not meant to be c++, the c++ is the template code in the question, this is just a hand debug of passing 3 args

```
min (a, b, c)
  First = a;
  Tailmin = min (b, c);
  if (first < Tailmin)
     return first;
  return Tailmin;

min (b, c)
  First = b;
  Tailmin = min (c);
  if (first < Tailmin)
     return first;
  return Tailmin;

min (c)
// base stops recursion
   return c
```

Comment: It answers the question with a paper trace of actual correct behavior, commented as such in answer.